# Applying Jquery to Html elements inside a tooltip

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I'm using tooltipster to display tooltips.

In the content of tooltipster,I want to display a checkbox

But the real problem is that I want to popup a alert box when a user clicks on the checkbox.But I'm unable to do so.I have tried using jquery change() method on the checkbox,but it doesn't help.
Can anyone suggest me a way to apply jquery on the check box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tooltipster dynamically appends html. therefore, you need to tell jquery to check condition live. This is done by [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Check this example:

```
$( "table" ).delegate( "td", "click", function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "chosen" );
});
```

Even if any script dynamically add new `TD` to the `TABLE` delegate will still work.

Comment: @Sibendu element which is parent to all tooltips. In extreme case you can use $("body") [Bad practise,but work]. And instead of "td" write selector for checkbox.

Comment: Thank god.It worked.Thanks!!Can't vote up as I don't have the requisite reputation..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trigger an alert on click, you can do that with jQuery pretty simply:

HTML:

```
<input id="trigger" type="checkbox" />
```

jQuery:

```
$('#trigger').click(function() {
  alert('you clicked me!');  
})
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Hq8V/)**